# How to display Product custom attributes on cart-show controller

Tags: commerce-cloud

I created one custom attribute called Estimated delivery date which I need to display on PDP and Cart-show page.

It is accessible on pdp page as product object available. But how I can get that value and display on cart-show page

Comment: Are you using SFRA or SiteGenesis?

Comment: @thomas i am using SFRA

Answer (score 0):

To get certain attributes available on the 'view' in SFRA for products, you need to add your attribute to the model.

This requires customizations to the code.

https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/storefront-reference-architecture/tree/master/cartridges%2Fapp_storefront_base%2Fcartridge%2Fmodels%2Fproduct